# Deploying war file using xml on jetty9

Tags: java, jetty

I am trying to deploy a war file on jetty9, it works fine if I drop it into webapps folder but I want to deploy it using a xml file.

Here's the exception I am getting:

```
2015-10-22 17:36:39.593:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@61a485d2{/myapp,file:///tmp/jetty-openbd.war-_myapp-any-1881803922382581907.dir/webapp/,null}{/opt/openbd.org/openbd.war}
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaInfConfiguration.preConfigure(MetaInfConfiguration.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.preConfigure(WebAppContext.java:474)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:510)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1510)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1435)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:75)
```

and my xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN"
   "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/myapp</Set>
  <Set name="war">/opt/openbd.org/openbd.war</Set>
</Configure>
```

I tried with `<Set name="extractWAR">true</Set>` with no luck.

I also used `--debug` which didn't provide any clue..

What am I doing wrong? Jetty version: jetty-9.3.3.v20150827

Comment: Include how you configured your `${jetty.base}` and how/where you are putting that XML.  You are putting your `myapp.xml` into the `${jetty.base}/webapps/` directory, right?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I put that xml on start.ini. here's my config: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12896366/

Comment: I think I will have to customize jetty-deploy.xml  for my needs drop that file into a folder I specify

Comment: It worked, created a customized version of jetty-deploy.xml to scan a different folder  and drop that myapp.xml into that folder. Now I would like to disable jetty.home./webapps, but apparently I can't remove deploy module otherwise the jars won't be on my classpath. is there a way to do that without changing jetty.home?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So for your scenario you'll need to understand how `${jetty.base}` and `${jetty.home}` operate.

**Step 1: The `${jetty.home}` directory**

Download and unpack the jetty distribution, anywhere, to any path you want to.

This is now your `${jetty.home}` directory.

These are the most important facts about `${jetty.home}`

- Don't edit it.
- Don't change a thing.
- Don't delete anything.
- Leave it alone.

You can have multiple `${jetty.home}` directories on your machine if you want.  They don't step on each other or cause any problems.

**Step 2: The `${jetty.base}` directory**

Create a new directory OUTSIDE of the `${jetty.home}` directory.

This new, now blank, directory is the start of your `${jetty.base}`.

A `${jetty.base}` represent the configuration for a specific instance of Jetty.  You can have multiple `${jetty.base}` directories as well.  Each directory represent a unique instance of a running Jetty.

The fundamental configuration for a `${jetty.base}` is the `start.ini` which is a set of command line arguments used to start jetty. (Similar to how all of the Eclipse RT projects out there work)

To initialize your `${jetty.base}` using command line tooling you can utilize the `${jetty.home}/start.jar` and its `--add-to-start=<module>` facilities.

Example:

```
$ cd /path/to/my.base
$ java -jar /path/to/jetty-dist/start.jar --add-to-start=http,deploy,websocket
```

Congrats you just initialized your `${jetty.base}` directory.

**Step 3: Adding your WebApps**

Since you chose the `deploy` module in the above step, you now have a `${jetty.base}/webapps` which is used by Jetty to auto-deploy the various web applications found within.

See the documentation on [the Deployment Architecture](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/deployment-architecture.html#default-web-app-provider) to understand what it looks for and how it deploys.

In your case, just put your `myapp.xml` into the `${jetty.base}/webapps/` directory.

> Note: Using the `deploy` module as-is, will only monitor and deploy from the `${jetty.base}/webapps/` directory.   No other directory is looked in, or monitored for web applications.  Not even the `${jetty.home}/webapps/` directory.

The monitored directory can be configured via a property in your `${jetty.base}/start.ini`.  Simply set `jetty.deploy.monitoredDir=<relative-path>` and this new path will be monitored (no editing of `jetty-deploy.xml` required).  The monitored directory is configured to always be under the specified `${jetty.base}` directory.  Seeing as the `${jetty.base}` directory can be anywhere on your filesystem, there should be no issues with using the `${jetty.base}` facilities.

**Step 4: Run Jetty**

This isn't that hard either.

```
$ cd /path/to/my.base
$ java -jar /path/to/jetty-dist/start.jar
```

Congrats you have a running jetty.

**Step 5: (Bonus) Listing the Configuration**

There's 2 ways to see what the configuration looks like.

1. See the server configuration, before you start jetty.

```
$ cd /path/to/my.base
$ java -jar /path/to/jetty-dist/start.jar --list-config
```

2. See the server state after it is fully started.

```
$ cd /path/to/my.base
$ java -jar /path/to/jetty-dist/start.jar jetty.server.dumpAfterStart=true
```